# postconf setting isn't "sticking"

Tags: postfix, zimbra

I need to set the Postfix `lmtp_host_lookup` setting to `native` instead of `dns`, which is the default. This is an artifact of the way I have Zimbra 7 installed on my Ubuntu 11.04 system, and local mail delivery works when I use /etc/hosts, thus the setting. However, the setting doesn't stick and keeps reverting back to `dns`, and local mail stops getting delivered until I manually reset it. Here are some details:

Here's the lines containing 'lookup' in postconf:

```
zimbra@ubuntu:~$ postconf | grep lookup
disable_dns_lookups = no
empty_address_default_transport_maps_lookup_key = <>
empty_address_relayhost_maps_lookup_key = <>
ignore_mx_lookup_error = yes
lmtp_host_lookup = dns
smtp_host_lookup = native
smtpd_null_access_lookup_key = <>
smtpd_peername_lookup = yes
```

I have previously set smtp_host_lookup to native, and that has remained. But lmtp_host_lookup keeps reverting to the default. I can then issue:

```
zimbra@ubuntu:~$ postconf -e lmtp_host_lookup=native
```

And the setting will be there:

```
zimbra@ubuntu:~$ postconf | grep lookup
disable_dns_lookups = no
empty_address_default_transport_maps_lookup_key = <>
empty_address_relayhost_maps_lookup_key = <>
ignore_mx_lookup_error = yes
lmtp_host_lookup = native
smtp_host_lookup = native
smtpd_null_access_lookup_key = <>
smtpd_peername_lookup = yes
```

This will start local mail delivery for a while. *However*, if I restart postfix, it reverts back to 'dns'. And at some seemingly random time, which tends to be a couple days, it will self-revert back to 'dns'.

Now a complete and total hack would be to put the setting in cron, but I want to get to the underlying issue. What could be the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Postfix configuration is rewritten each time service is (re)started.
Value for `lmtp_host_lookup` is taken from zimbra local config named `postfix_lmtp_host_lookup` as configured in template file for rewritting (`/opt/zimbra/conf/zmmta.cf`) which contains

```
POSTCONF lmtp_host_lookup                     LOCAL postfix_lmtp_host_lookup
```

To edit `postfix_lmtp_host_lookup`, just run

```
zmlocalconfig -e postfix_lmtp_host_lookup=native
```

and restart postfix (`zmmtactl restart`).

Comment: Thanks, I'll try this. What would cause the file to get overwritten even when I haven't restarted Zimbra?

Comment: Postfix configuration is not expected to be edited directly. Any change in admin interface, periodic tasks in cron, zmmailboxd or anything else can trigger zmmtactl reload, thus rewriting configuration.